# Failed import for Sentry_sdk in Django

Tags: python, django, sentry

I am currently trying to get Sentry to work with my Django project. While initializing Sentry in the settings.py file I get this error:

line 301, in module
import sentry_sdk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sentry_sdk'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)

I copied the docs, and I'm wondering why this is happening. Has anyone experienced this issue before? My Django version is 2.2.11 and I'm running python v 3.9.5

Here is the code for the docs if it matters (pip install --upgrade sentry-sdk)

```
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.django import DjangoIntegration

sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn="https://examplePublicKey@o0.ingest.sentry.io/0",
    integrations=[DjangoIntegration()],

    # Set traces_sample_rate to 1.0 to capture 100%
    # of transactions for performance monitoring.
    # We recommend adjusting this value in production,
    traces_sample_rate=1.0,

    # If you wish to associate users to errors (assuming you are using
    # django.contrib.auth) you may enable sending PII data.
    send_default_pii=True,

    # By default the SDK will try to use the SENTRY_RELEASE
    # environment variable, or infer a git commit
    # SHA as release, however you may want to set
    # something more human-readable.
    # release="myapp@1.0.0",
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you have installed `sentry` in your environment?
Ensure you ran `pip install sentry-sdk` in the same environment you are running your code from

Comment: Yeah it's installed

Comment: Did you find an answer? I face the same problem.

Comment: install sentry in the same `virtualenv` as well and if warning is not gone yet try restarting the editor. sometimes it gets stuck (faced it). pylance coudn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I had to include sentry-sdk==1.1.0 in my requirements file to get it to run.

Comment: This may work if you use docker, since the requirements file is used by docker to create the image. You may also need to delete/rebuild your image after you add this.